# Убрать отступ перед элементом ul?

Tags: css3, html5

Как убрать отступ, который выделен фиолетовым на картинке?

```css
.info__left {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
}

.header__supheader {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fef7f6;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__supheader">
  <ul class="info__left">
    <li class="line">PHONE: +01 256 25 235</li>
    <li class="line">EMAIL: info@eiser.com</li>
  </ul>
  <nav class="info__right">
    <a class="info__right__link" href="#">gift card</a>
    <a class="info__right__link" href="#">track order</a>
    <a class="info__right__link" href="#">language</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Судя по всему вы недавно начали заниматься версткой, перед применением своих стилей лучше сбросить браузерные стили (у разных браузеров могут быт разные отступы для элементов, по умолчанию) Если же вы этого не сделаете, то `ul` это только начало. Проще всего сбросить стили с помощью готового [reset.css](https://github.com/jasonkarns/css-reset/blob/master/reset.css) или [normilize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) для начала, потом создадите свой файл сброса.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы убрать отступ у `<ul>` нужно прописать ему в стили:

```
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Пример:

```css
.info__left {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="info__left">
  <li class="line">PHONE: +01 256 25 235</li>
  <li class="line">EMAIL: info@eiser.com</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для `.line` установить `margin: 0 20px 0 0;`.

```css
.info__left {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.header__supheader {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fef7f6;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: outside;
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__supheader">
  <ul class="info__left">
    <li class="line">PHONE: +01 256 25 235</li>
    <li class="line">EMAIL: info@eiser.com</li>
  </ul>
  <nav class="info__right">
    <a class="info__right__link" href="#">gift card</a>
    <a class="info__right__link" href="#">track order</a>
    <a class="info__right__link" href="#">language</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: better solution: ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}